# PHP decode data JSON/SERIALIZED

Tags: php, serialization, json

I cant get this into an array..

I should decode this with php:

```
({serverTimestamp: "Wed, 28 Mar 2012 11:40:26 +0000",users: [{userId: "username",statuscode:0,floatingPL:-1000.00,balance:50000,equity:40000,freeMargin:4000,marginInUse:30.11,currency:"EUR",closedPL:5692.85,creditFacility:0,mostRecentUpload:"Wed, 28 Mar 2012 11:39:58 +0000"}]})
```

It looks like it's serialized, but unserialize() gives false in var_dump(). Json_decode gives the same..

Thank you

Comment: Property names in JSON must be quoted. It isn't JSON.

Comment: And loose those `(` and `)` brackets...

Answer (score 2):

Example: http://codepad.org/tK4zIJj1

- JSON is defined here: http://www.json.org/
- property names **must** be always double quoted
- loose the `(...)` brackets
- use `json_decode()` http://hu2.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

`serialize()` vs `unserialize()` are PHP's own data from/to string conversion functions, which can deal with circular references, classes, etc. but usually not compatible with the outer world.

1. You should kick the ass of the provider of the "JSON" data to fix it.
2. If ass-kicking didn't help, you can use this quickly put-together function:

   ```
   function fix_json( $j ){
     $j = trim( $j );
     $j = ltrim( $j, '(' );
     $j = rtrim( $j, ')' );
     $a = preg_split('#(?<!\\\\)\"#', $j );
     for( $i=0; $i < count( $a ); $i+=2 ){
       $s = $a[$i];
       $s = preg_replace('#([^\s\[\]\{\}\:\,]+):#', '"\1":', $s );
       $a[$i] = $s;
     }
     //var_dump($a);
     $j = implode( '"', $a );
     //var_dump( $j );
     return $j;
   }
   ```

   Example: http://codepad.org/9MpZVWrF

Comment: Thank you, but I get this data form an external url, not my site, how can I add those double quotes around the property names?

Comment: Dont't forget to test it before use! If it really works, please accept the correct answer :)

Comment: just an upvote -'cause that's a lot of work for not even getting accepted!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ghoti is right. In order for PHP to convert to JSON, all property names must be quoted in double quotes. In this case, this is the correct JSON:

```
({"serverTimestamp": "Wed, 28 Mar 2012 11:40:26 +0000","users": [{"userId": "username","statuscode":0,"floatingPL":-1000.00,"balance":50000,"equity":40000,"freeMargin":4000,"marginInUse":30.11,"currency":"EUR","closedPL":5692.85,"creditFacility":0,"mostRecentUpload":"Wed, 28 Mar 2012 11:39:58 +0000"}]})
```

Comment: Thank you, but I get this data form an external url, not my site, how can I add those double quotes around the property names?